# Building calendar in React including Click and drag to select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar

I’m trying to create a google calendar like weekly scheduler using react. I want to be able to select and drag a part of a day by selecting the time slots to create an event. I have no idea how to proceed. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to create it from scratch, it will be long and error prone.
Hence, it is better to utilize a library which provides Calendar.

Example:
https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar-ui-qcalendar
This is for Vue. But you will find similar for react too.